# Create enum with special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I create an enum with special characters. For example, I want to create an enum for "blood_group" and its values include O+, O-, A+, A-, etc). I could have a helper method that converts an enum to the desired string representation (for example, I could convert "o_positive" to "O+", but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually an enum would be implemented somehow like this

```
enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
```

and then used like

```
Article.active
Article.active?
Article.active!
```

So by including symbols you would get something like:

```
Blood.O+ || Blood.O-
```

And this isn't thought to work, as let's say you normally use those to **add** or **subtract**. Even other variables, you can't write `my-variable`, it has to be `my_variable`.

So just look at the `+` and `-` as reserved characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
 enum blood_group: ["O+", "O-","A+","A-"]
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 helper_method :method_name
 def convert(str)
  sym= nil
  a= str.split("_")
  if str.split("_").last == "positive"
  sym = "+" 
  else
  sym = "-"
  end
  return (str.split("_").first + sym).upcase
end
end
```